# update stripe payment intent from wallet payment without creating a customer

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am attempting to integrate wallets (Google/Apple Pay) into an existing Stripe elements page.

```
const paymentRequest = stripe.paymentRequest({
            country: 'GB',
            currency: 'gbp',
            total: {
                label: 'Demo total',
                amount: 1000,
            },
        });


        paymentRequest.addEventListener('token', (event) =>
        {
            //const token = event.paymentMethod.token;
            // Handle the token event here
            if (event.token)
            {
                let token = event.token.id;
                let payerName = event.payerName;
                let payerEmail = event.payerEmail;
                let payerPhone = event.payerPhone;

                stripeWalletToken(token);
            }

            event.complete('success');
        });

        paymentRequest.addEventListener('source', (event) =>
        {
            if (event.source)
            {
                let payerName = event.payerName;
                let payerEmail = event.payerEmail;
                let payerPhone = event.payerPhone;

                let source = event.source.id;
                // Handle the source event here
                stripeWalletSource(source);                
            }
            // Handle the source event here
            event.complete('success');
        });


        const prButton = elements.create('paymentRequestButton', {
            paymentRequest: paymentRequest,
            style: {
                paymentRequestButton: {
                    type: 'default',
                    theme: 'dark',
                    height: '64px',
                },
            },
        });
```

Once I receive the source id, I send it to my server and try to update the PaymentIntent as such:

```
    if (i != null)
    {
        var options = new PaymentIntentUpdateOptions
        {
        PaymentMethod = "pm_card_yournewsourceid", // Replace with your new PaymentMethod ID
        };

        var service = new PaymentIntentService();
        PaymentIntent updatedPaymentIntent = service.Update(i.Id, options);

    }
```

However I get the message "A source must be attached to a customer to be used as a payment_method". I do not want to create a customer on Stripe's platform. I simply want to update the existing payment intent with the payment that has been received from Google/Apple.

I have tried consulting Stripe's 'documentation' and there's nothing to cover it. Their support staff are unable to understand the issue, let alone provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're using Tokens - which you shouldn't do.

I'd suggest following the up-to-date documentation on Stripe's Payment Request Element, which doesn't tokenize the card wallet using the Tokens API, but the Payment Methods API:
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button

Your integration differs from this documentation, notably on the `paymentRequest.on('payment_method',{})` and `stripe.confirmPayment({})`:
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?client=html#html-js-complete-payment

Comment: yep. Unfortunately with no realistic support available from Stripe on the weekends I ended up asking ChatGPT for help and ended up down the token/source rabbit hole as that was the only event which appeared to be firing. Since removing that and resetting the paymentRequest..on(paymentmoethod) the paymentmethod now appears to be firing!